# Why this cookie returns me null when I call it from other function[IE]

Tags: jquery, xml

Below is the structure of my program to store some data in cookie for later access

```
function xmlSet()
{
   var qTypes = ["Single","Multi","Grid","Open","Grid3D"];
   for(var i = 0;i<qTypes.length;i++)
   {
        SingleReader(qTypes[i]);
   }
}
```

and

```
function SingleReader(eleType)
{
  var xmlDat = $.parseXML($('#xmlText').val());
  var xml = $(xmlDat);
  var path = xml.find('ProjectID').text();
  xml.find(''+eleType+'').each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('name');
    var dat = $(this).text('');
    $.cookies.set(id,dat);
    //Here I am testing whether cookie is being stored or not  
    alert($.cookies.get(id)); // Returns value which was before.  
  };
  alert($.cookies.get("M")) // Here "M" is known Item but it returns me null when I access outside the function
}
```

This happens only in IE.  Please help me on this,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$.cookie('cookie_name', 'our value', { path: '/', expires: 10000 });
//then try alerting out of function
```